jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $j(...).select2 is not a function
When I log in and view the home page, the Testimonial carousel works fine. However, when I view it without logging in, it doesn’t function properly. I’ve observed that an error appears in the console when I access the page without logging in. I'm not sure why carousel not working, Could you please helps us to solve this issue. Here is my URL https://www.absolute-aromas.com/
https://c0.wp.com/c/6.5.5/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js
Uncaught TypeError: $j(...).select2 is not a function
    at initSelect2 (woocommerce.min.js:1:108)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (woocommerce.min.js:1:7710)
    at e (jquery.min.js:2:27028)
    at t (jquery.min.js:2:27330)

jQuery.Deferred exception: $j(...).select2 is not a function TypeError: $j(...).select2 is not a function
    at initSelect2 (https://www.absolute-aromas.com/wp-content/cache/w3-cache/js/13/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/woocommerce.min.js:1:108)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (https://www.absolute-aromas.com/wp-content/cache/w3-cache/js/13/wp-content/themes/bridge/js/woocommerce.min.js:1:7710)
    at e (https://c0.wp.com/c/6.5.5/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:27028)
    at t (https://c0.wp.com/c/6.5.5/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js:2:27330) undefined


I tried to disable cache but it's not working, few days ago it's working properly.

seems like you applied select2 on an element which only available when you are logged in.

or the select2 asset isn't being loaded at all (because coming from a not valid url or behind authenication need?) .. speculations. By the way start checking if the selector you are using actually returns an existing element

I have checked the given link, you need to convert below:
function initSelect2() {
    $j(".woocommerce-ordering .orderby, #calc_shipping_country, #dropdown_product_cat").select2({
        minimumResultsForSearch: -1
    }),
    $j(".woocommerce-account .country_select").select2()
}

To:
function initSelect2() {
    if($j(".woocommerce-ordering .orderby").length > 0){
        $j(".woocommerce-ordering .orderby").select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1
        });
    }
    if($j("#calc_shipping_country").length > 0){
        $j("#calc_shipping_country").select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1
        });
    }
    if($j("#dropdown_product_cat").length > 0){
        $j("#dropdown_product_cat").select2({
            minimumResultsForSearch: -1
        });
    }
    if($j(".woocommerce-account .country_select").length > 0 ){
        $j(".woocommerce-account .country_select").select2()
    }
}

What is updated here: First check whether the element is available or not, if yes then only apply select2
